# How do I use an MSBuild file from Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, build-automation

I have a simple MSBuild file that I'm learning with.

Here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Clean" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectGuid>{D5A16164-962E-4A6D-9382-240F31AB6C50}</ProjectGuid>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="Clean">
    <ItemGroup>
      <BinFiles Include="bin\*.*" />
      <fff Include="f\*.*" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Delete Files="@(BinFiles)" />
    <Delete Files="@(fff)" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Now I want to include this in a Visual Studio solution and be able to run the "clean" target from Visual Studio 2012. I tried naming it `testproject.msbuildproj` like the internet seems to suggest "works", but it doesn't work. When I run the clean command I just get "unexpected error".

If I rename the project to `testproject.csproj`, it does some unintuitive things like creating compilation directories, but it does actually run my clean command properly. However, this is undesireable because it creates `obj` and `bin/x86/debug` type directories. It also looks goofy in Visual Studio because it still gives the References drop down.

How can I use just a plain vanilla MSBuild project from Visual Studio without random errors or false assumptions?

Note I only am having a problem with this from Visual Studio. Using msbuild from the command line it works perfectly

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio creates bin / obj folders when it **opens** csproj file. When you click Build / Rebuild / Clean it just uses appropriate targets from the project file.

You cannot stop VS from creating these folders, but you can ask it to create them in say temp folder by setting appropriate properties - refer [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629394.aspx) for details.

So the steps are to rename your project to `csproj`, and add the following lines into project:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <OutputPath>$(Temp)\bin</OutputPath>
  <IntermediateOutputPath>$(Temp)\obj</IntermediateOutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I usually use a bit different approach to work with MSBUILD files from VS:

- I use regular `csproj` file with removed `Import ... CSharp.targets` part as pure container for my Build projects.
- I add actual build files with targets and logic, and all properties, necessary artifacts like XSLT etc using "Include into project", so I can manage hierarchy and change any file from within VS.Net.
- I redefine `Build` / `Rebuild` targets in `csproj` file for whatever I need, for example Build may contain minimum output, and while rebuild diagnostic one.

Like this:

```
<Target Name="Build">
  <Exec Command="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe Builds\build.proj /t:Build /v:m" />
</Target>
<Target Name="Rebuild">
  <Exec Command="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe Builds\build.proj /t:Build /v:d" />
</Target>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to actually answer the question: "How ..." You have suggested setup for MSBuild execution within VS, but you have not answered how to execute MSBuild from VS.

Comment: @IAbstract Thanks for downvote. If you read question carefully `If I rename the project to testproject.csproj ... it does actually run my clean command properly. However, this is undesireable because it creates obj and bin/x86/debug type directories` I describe a way how to run Clean/Build/Rebuild from msbuild project without bin/obj artifacts.